# Dynamic Form Generate using Blazor Component

Tags: blazor

I have following code, where I generate Form based on each property from the Model based on DataType Attribute. This code works fine and generates three textboxes

---

**Model:** **(ContactDetails.cs)**

```
public class ContactDetails
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

---

**Dynamic Form Generator:** **(DynamicForm.razor)**

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
@using System.Reflection;

@typeparam TItem

@if (ObjDynamicModel != null)
{
    if (ParentContainer == null)
    {
        <EditForm Model="@ObjDynamicModel" OnValidSubmit=@OnValidSubmitEventHandler OnInvalidSubmit="@OnInvalidSubmitEventHandler" class="row gx-3 gy-2 align-items-center">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary />
            @ChildContainer(RenderDynamicForm)
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
    }
    else
    {
        @ParentContainer(
         @:@{
        <EditForm Model="@ObjDynamicModel" OnValidSubmit=@OnValidSubmitEventHandler OnInvalidSubmit="@OnInvalidSubmitEventHandler" class="row gx-3 gy-2 align-items-center">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary />
            @ChildContainer(RenderDynamicForm)
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
        }
        )
    }
}
else
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <strong>No Fields to display.</strong>
    </div>
}


@code {
    [Parameter] public TItem? ObjDynamicModel { get; set; }    
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<EditContext> OnValidSubmitEventCallback { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<EditContext> OnInvalidSubmitEventCallback { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<RenderFragment> ParentContainer { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<RenderFragment> ChildContainer { get; set; }
        
    protected RenderFragment? RenderDynamicForm { get; set; }

    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        RenderDynamicForm = new RenderFragment(CreateDynamicForm);
    }

    protected void OnValidSubmitEventHandler(EditContext editContext)
    {
        OnValidSubmitEventCallback.InvokeAsync(editContext);
    }

    protected void OnInvalidSubmitEventHandler(EditContext editContext)
    {
        OnInvalidSubmitEventCallback.InvokeAsync(editContext);
    }

    public void CreateDynamicForm(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        if (ObjDynamicModel != null)
        {
            Type ObjType = ObjDynamicModel.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] PropertyList = ObjType.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in PropertyList)
            {
                CreateDynamicControl(builder, ObjType, property);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void CreateDynamicControl(RenderTreeBuilder builder, Type ObjType, PropertyInfo property)
    {
        bool CreateFieldSuccess = false;
        if (property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataTypeAttribute), false).Length != 0)
        {
            DataTypeAttribute dataTypeAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes<DataTypeAttribute>(false).First();
            DisplayAttribute displayAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes<DisplayAttribute>(false).First();

            // /CREATE AN EXPRESSION TO SET THE VALUEEXPRESSION-ATTRIBUTE.
            ConstantExpression constantExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(ObjDynamicModel, ObjType);
            MemberExpression memberExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Property(constantExpression, property.Name);
            switch (dataTypeAttribute.DataType)
            {
                case DataType.Text:
                case DataType.EmailAddress:
                case DataType.PhoneNumber:
                case DataType.MultilineText:
                    {
                        CreateFieldSuccess = CreateInputText(builder, property, memberExpression);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    // /DO NOTHING.
                    break;
            }

            if (CreateFieldSuccess)
            {
                var defaultValue = property?.GetValue(ObjDynamicModel);
                if (defaultValue != null) { builder.AddAttribute(1, "Value", defaultValue); }
                builder.AddAttribute(2, "PlaceHolder", displayAttribute.Name);
                builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", "form-control");
                builder.AddMarkupContent(5, "\r\n    ");
                builder.CloseComponent();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool CreateInputText(RenderTreeBuilder builder, PropertyInfo property, MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        bool CreateFieldSuccess;
        builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(InputText));

        // /CREATE THE HANDLER FOR VALUE CHANGED USING REFLECTION TO THE VALUE.
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "ValueChanged", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.String?>>
                (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<System.String?>
                    (this, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateInferred
                        (this, __value => property.SetValue(ObjDynamicModel, __value)
                            , (string?)property.GetValue(ObjDynamicModel)))));

        builder.AddAttribute(4, "ValueExpression", System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(memberExpression));
        
        CreateFieldSuccess = true;
        return CreateFieldSuccess;
    }
}
```

---

**Usage:** **(Index.razor)**

```
@page "/"
@using DynamicForm.Data;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Render Dynamic Form</h1>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="form-row">
        <DynamicForm TItem="object"
            ObjDynamicModel="@ObjDynamicModel"
            OnValidSubmitEventCallback="@HandleValidFormSubmit"
            OnInvalidSubmitEventCallback="@HandleInValidFormSubmit" Context="CustomDynamicForm">
            <ParentContainer>
                <div class="container" @key="CustomDynamicForm">
                    <div class="row gx-3 gy-2 align-items-center">
                        @CustomDynamicForm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ParentContainer>
            <ChildContainer Context="CustomDynamicContrrol">
                <div class="col-md-3" @key="CustomDynamicContrrol">
                    @CustomDynamicContrrol
                </div>
            </ChildContainer>
        </DynamicForm>
    </div>
</div>

@code{
    private object? ObjDynamicModel { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ObjDynamicModel = new ContactDetails();
    }

    protected void HandleValidFormSubmit(EditContext editContext)
    {

    }

    protected void HandleInValidFormSubmit(EditContext editContext)
    {

    }
}
```

---

**With above code the output is:**

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
<!--!--><input placeholder="Name" class="form-control valid" _bl_6d4d71e7-1632-40a6-93a0-056fbcf713e0="">
<!--!--><input placeholder="Email" class="form-control valid" _bl_56c20a21-989f-49e7-bac9-cee261d32620="">
<!--!--><input placeholder="Phone" class="form-control valid" _bl_c4348f49-a9f5-4aed-b7dd-cb02ebdec22e="">
</div>
```

---

**Expected Output is:**

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
<!--!--><input placeholder="Name" class="form-control valid" _bl_f0d1f743-3f67-4448-b6de-4a743e361f3c="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<!--!--><input placeholder="Email" class="form-control valid" _bl_821d41f6-c893-4c86-acc4-0eae561638b9="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<!--!--><input placeholder="Phone" class="form-control valid" _bl_f727b46e-0ba1-4e73-b00e-e5c90716ac5f="">
</div>
```

---

Currently DynamicForm.razor has CreateDynamicForm method which runs a loop and creates Dynamic Fields and adds it to a RenderTreeBuilder. I understand that the ChildContainer with in EditForm (@ChildContainer(RenderDynamicForm)) should be surrounded with a loop for each PropertyInfo from the model. And I also created a CustomRenderFragment delegate to call CreateDynamicControl method from the loop. So that each generated dynamic field is wrapped within a ChildContainer. But only Cancel and Save button shows and form is all empty. No error on the page.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much in advance for your support, suggestion and feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Syncfusion has a pretty neat dynamic form example and is not as complicated as your implementation. Maybe you can get some inspiration from it: https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/blazor-dynamic-form.

Comment: Very interesting how you perform this. It's an idea, but maybe you can create a List<RenderFragment> containing the inputText for each properties. Instead of one whole RenderDynamicForm.
And in the razor code, make a loop over this list and calling the ChildContainer(fragment)